# How do I get back the default Ubuntu fonts after installing wine?

Tags: wine, fonts

I installed wine and now I notice a different font on facebook and a couple of other sites I use a lot. So, how do I get back the default Ubuntu fonts?

Comment: @potential answerers: I believe that wine has instlled some extra fonts, as a couple of font packages are recommended by wine. It's likely that liberation or mscorefonts are the culprights. But I don't really know of a good way to uninstall mscorefonts, so I hope that someone can give a good answer. If no ones does, I'll try mu best.

Comment: Thanks! I will wait for someone who can help me to fix the issue or else I will bug you :)

Comment: Can you please include a screenshot so we know if what you're seeing is "wrong"?

Comment: I see different fonts. There is no issue as such but I would like to revert back to previous ones

Comment: More importantly, and also to add some keywords to this post, this will remove Arial and Comic. How dare they put that *§$% on my computer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Installing wine will also push the "ttf-mscorefonts-installer" package which brings some aditional fonts.

You can remove it without removing wine, but it can negatively affect the look of some applications running from wine.

To remove it, open a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get purge ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

Comment: That easy?. I was expecting that this command will only uninstall the installer. I suppose that it includes a uninstall script too. That's great :).

Comment: The package behaves as a normal font package, it just has a peculiar name due to the licensing behind it.  We can't ship the fonts directly, instead we have to download them at package install time.

Answer (score 5):

Another work around for me is using command `sudo apt-get install wine --no-install-recommends`. It only install the wine only.

Comment: at least comment why you downvote it? :/