# Ubuntu fonts are wrong after installing Wine and MS "corefonts"

Tags: 13.10, fonts

I installed Wine as well as the "MS corefonts" add-on.

The fonts inside my Windows apps are okay, but the fonts **in Ubuntu** are wrong -- both the monospace font used in forms like the one *this post* is written in, and also the regular fonts used throughout Firefox and elsewhere in Ubuntu - they look smudgy and ugly, like a 1990-era version of ClearType. Gmail in particular is horrible, especially the font in the compose window.

**How can I get the regular fonts back?**

I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 with stock Unity, no custom skin or anything. I've looked in the "system settings" but I don't see any obvious place that controls fonts. "Universal access" is turned off, and my display settings are okay (correct resolution etc.).

In Firefox preferences, in the "content" section, the selected "default font" is "serif" 16 point.

Comment: You can check and reset your fonts easily by installing `ubuntu-tweak`. However, installing Wine should not change the system default fonts.

Comment: Thanks @Jos I have now installed `ubuntu-tweak` and the fonts seem to be fine, including subpixel rendering etc. So it's not that. [This answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/25483/how-do-i-get-back-the-default-ubuntu-fonts-after-installing-wine?rq=1) seems to have a promising answer, but I'm not sure what it will do to my Wine installation so I'm hesitating to just try it out.